# ¿Que se puede hacer para simular un try catch de MS SQL pero en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

**¿Que se puede hacer para simular un try catch de Microsoft SQL Server pero en PostgreSQL?**

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID_USUARIO = @ID_RESPONSABLE)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @ID_CLIENTE INT
                SET @ID_CLIENTE = (SELECT ID_MEMBRESIA FROM CLIENTES WHERE
                @NOMBRE = NOMBRE AND
                @APELLIDO_P = APELLIDO_P AND
                @APELLIDO_M = APELLIDO_M AND
                @FECHA_NAC = FECHA_NAC
                )

                IF @ID_CLIENTE IS NULL
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO CLIENTES
                        VALUES (@ID_MEMBRESIA,@NOMBRE,@APELLIDO_P,@APELLIDO_M,
                        @FECHA_NAC,@CALLE,@NUMERO,@COLONIA,@CODIGO_P,@MUNICIPIO,@LOCALIDAD,@ESTADO,'SI')

                        INSERT INTO BITACORA VALUES 
                        (@ID_RESPONSABLE, 'CLIENTES',('Dio de alta un nuevo cliente: '+
                        @NOMBRE +' '+@APELLIDO_P+' '+@APELLIDO_M),
                        GETDATE())

                        SET @STATUS = 'true'
                        SET @MENSAJE = 'Se ha registrado un nuevo cliente satisfactoriamente'
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MENSAJE = 'Este cliente ya existe en la base de datos'
                        PRINT @MENSAJE
                        SET @STATUS ='false'
                    END
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN 
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usuario denegado. Operaciòn inclompleta'
                PRINT @MENSAJE
                SET @STATUS ='false'
            END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @STATUS = 'false'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis para atrapar excepciones en PostgreSQL es una extensión de la sintaxis normal utilizada para un bloque `BEGIN` con una cláusula `EXCEPTION`:

Suponiendo que tenemos el registro en usuarios:

```
| id | nombres | apellidos |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | Alan    | Rodriguez |
```

Ejecutamos:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE usuarios SET nombres = 'Joe' WHERE apellidos = 'Rodriguez';
    x := x + 1;
    y := x / 0;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN division_por_cero THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Error: ¡División por cero!';
        RETURN x;
END;
```

De forma predeterminada, cualquier error que se produzca en una función PostgreSQL anula la ejecución de la función y también de la transacción circundante.

Cuando el control llegue a la asignación de `y`, fallará con un error de `division_por_cero`. Esto será capturado por la cláusula `EXCEPTION`. El valor devuelto en la declaración `RETURN` será el valor incrementado de x, pero los efectos del comando `UPDATE` se habrán revertido.

Por lo que el resultado final es que en la base de datos tienes registrado a *Alan Rodriguez* y no a *Joe Rodriguez*.

---

Puedes leer más sobre esto en la [documentación oficial de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)